# How is use of naagastra by karna justified if other scriptures invalidate it?

Tags: weapon, karna

Quoting from mahabharat [here](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08090.htm)

> The Suta's son then fixed on his bow-string that foe-killing,
> exceedingly keen, snake-mouthed, blazing, and fierce shaft, which had
> been polished ***according to rule, and which he had long kept for the
> sake of Partha's destruction.***

Manu 7.90

While fighting his enemies in battle, he shall hot strike with concealed weapons; nor with arrows that are poisoned, or barbed, or with flaming shafts.

Baudhāyana (1.18.10).—‘He shall not strike with barbed or poisoned arrows.’

So,I have two questions

1. Did Karna not know such rules, or were these rules made after the war?
2. Are these rules only for hand-made weapons? Not the weapons given by God or in any boon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mahabharata, it is acknowledged that there are some unfair weapons (similar to the ones mentioned by Dharmashastras in the question).

[Drona Parva, describing one of the fights, that happened to use fair weapons](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07186.htm)

> Those bulls among men, however, viz., the twins, Nakula and Sahadeva following in the wake of Dhrishtadyumna who was thus proceeding like a blazing fire towards Drona, began to protect him. Then, all those great car-warriors, endued with might and excited with rage, began to strike one another, making death their goal. Of pure souls and pure conduct, O king, and keeping heaven in view, they fought according to righteous methods, desirous of vanquishing one another. Of stainless lineage and stainless acts, and endued with great intelligence, those rulers of men, keeping heaven in view, fought fair battles with another. **There was nothing unfair in that fight and no weapon was used that was regarded as unfair. No barbed arrows, nor those called nalikas, nor those that are poisoned, nor those with heads, made of horns, nor those equipped with many pointed heads, nor those made of the bones of bulls and elephants, nor those having two heads, nor those having rusty heads, nor those that are not straight going, were used by any of them. All of them used simple and fair weapons and desired to win both fame and region of great blessedness by fighting fairly.** Between those four warriors of thy army and those three of the Pandava side, the battle that took place was exceedingly dreadful but divested of everything unfair.

**But it looks like these rules are not always followed in the Mahabharata war.**

[Bhishma Parva](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06096.htm)

> And foot-soldiers, attacked by bodies of foot-soldiers with darts and lances, fell down on the earth by hundreds and thousands. **And car-warriors upon their cars, slaughtering heroic adversaries in that battle by means of barbed arrows** and muskets and shafts, uttered leonine shouts.

[Karna parva](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08081.htm)

> Then a force of Mlecchas riding thirteen hundred ever-infuriated elephants, at the command of thy son, assailed Partha in the flank. With **barbed arrows and Nalikas** and cloth-yard shafts and lances and spears and darts and Kampanas and short arrows, they afflicted Partha on his car.

[Drona parva](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07135.htm)

> The mighty-armed Bhimasena, the son of Pandu, though thus struck by the Suta's son, showed no signs of pain but stood immovable like a hill pierced (with arrows). In return, O sire, in that battle, he deeply pierced Karna in the ear with a **barbed arrow**, rubbed with oil, of great keenness, and of excellent temper. (With that arrow) he felled on the earth the large and beautiful ear-ring of Karna.

[Karna Parva](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08020.htm)

> Thus addressed, Pandya answered, "So be it." Then Drona's son, telling him "Strike," assailed him with vigour. In return, Malayadhwaja pierced the son of Drona with a **barbed arrow.**

[Drona Parva](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07045.htm)

> Sanjaya said, 'Phalguni's son once more pierced Karna in the car with a **barbed arrow**, and for angering him still further, he pierced him with fifty other shafts.

[Stri Parva](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m11/m11018.htm)

> The youthful and brave and handsome Vikarna, O bull among men, brought up in luxury and deserving of every kind of weal, now sleepeth amid the dust, O Madhava! **Though all his vital parts have been pierced with clothyard shafts and bearded arrows and nalikas,** yet that beauty of person which was his hath not forsaken this best of the Bharatas.

[Udyoga Parva](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05141.htm), with Karna talking about the future Mahabharata war, with Krishna, comparing to a sacrifice

> The two sons of Madri, Nakula and Sahadeva, of great fame and prowess, will be the slayers of the sacrificial animals; rows of bright cars furnished with standards of variegated hue, will, O Govinda, be stakes (for tying the animals), O Janardana, in this sacrifice. **Barbed arrows and Nalikas**, and long shafts, and arrows with heads like calf's tooth, will play the part of spoons (wherewith to distribute the Soma juice) while Tomaras will be the vessels of Soma, and bows will be pavitras.

The above also shows that usage of unfair means like barbed arrows and nalikas, was expected even before the war.

[Stri parva](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m11/m11022.htm)

> Behold that hero, O Krishna, who in knowledge of duty was equal to Devapi himself, now lying on a bed of arrows, so worthy of heroes. **Having spread his excellent bed of barbed and unbarbed arrows**, that hero lieth on it like the divine Skanda on a clump of heath. Indeed, the son of Ganga lieth, resting his head on that excellent pillow, consisting of three arrows,--becoming complement of his bed--given him by the wielder of gandiva

Comment: Are these rules only for hand-made weapons? Not the weapons given by God or in any boon?

Comment: @Hope No exception is mentioned in the rules for any weapons given by devatas.